# Datos de la llamada no se imprimen

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Tengo un problema con un proyecto, necesito que los datos de mi llamada se impriman pero solo funcionan cuando se usa el botón del modal que anteriormente estaba habilitado

este es el código donde hace la llamada de los datos, pero solo funciona con el botón

```
                        <!-- SE REALIZA LA IMPRESIÓN DE LOS HORARIOS POR ENTRENIMIENTO -->
                    <div class="restaurant-tabs">
                        <div class="tabs tabs-restaurant" >
                            <h2 class="lbl-rest-section text-center">
                                <strong>{{"RESTAURANT.restaurant_dias" | translate}}</strong>
                            </h2>
                            <div class="tabview-container" *ngIf="hasScheduleData; else noDays" >
                                <a 
                                    *ngIf="enable_scroll_days" 
                                    href="javascript:void(0);" 
                                    class="tabview-scroll-btn tabview-scroll-btn-left" 
                                    (click)="scrollPrevious('tabview-custom-days')">
                                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
                                </a>
                                <p-tabView
                                    (onChange)="selectTab($event)"
                                    styleClass="tabview-custom-days">
                                    <p-tabPanel *ngFor="let apertura of schedule">
                                        <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                                            <span class="tab-header-item">
                                                {{apertura.apertura}}
                                            </span>
                                        </ng-template>
                                        <div class="gallery-cat activiti-cat text-center">
                                          <ul class="list-group">
                                              <li class="list-hour-schedule list-group-item" *ngFor="let item_horario of apertura.horario">   
                                                <span class="rest-day-lbl">
                                                    {{item_horario.dia}}
                                                </span>
                                                <span class="rest-day-lbl">
                                                    <strong>{{item_horario.hora_inicio}} - {{item_horario.hora_final}}</strong>    
                                                </span>
                                                </li>
                                          </ul>
                                      </div>
                                    </p-tabPanel>
                                </p-tabView>
                                <a 
                                    *ngIf="enable_scroll_days" 
                                    href="javascript:void(0);" 
                                    class="tabview-scroll-btn tabview-scroll-btn-right" 
                                    (click)="scrollNext('tabview-custom-days')">
                                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <ng-template #noDays>
                                <div class="avail-days-container" style="text-align: center;">
                                    <span> {{"RESTAURANT.restaurant_availabilityDays" | translate}} </span>
                                </div>
                            </ng-template>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Este es el código del botón que hace la llamada

```
                        <!-- SE DESHABILITA BOTÓN PARA MODAL EN ENTERTAINMENT-->
                    <div class="bot">
                        <button class="awe-btn awe-btn-13 pull-left" (click)="getActivityDetails(activity.id)">
                            {{"RESTAURANT.restaurant_details" | translate}}
                        </button>                            
                    </div>
```

Estos son los métodos que se usan para mandar a traer los datos en el component.ts

este sirve para traer los datos de nombre, imágenes y descripciones, este hace una llamada a la API

```
  getActivities(lang){
this.ngxLoader.start();
this._entertainmentService.getActivities(lang).subscribe(
  response => {
    this.activities = response.actividad;
    console.log(this.activities)    
    this.ngxLoader.stop();
  },
  error => {
    this.ngxLoader.stop();
    this.error = true;
  }
);
}
```

Ese método funciona correctamente, el problema está al imprimir los datos de los horarios correspondientes a cada evento o dato, este es el método, Este método funciona con una llamada a la API diferente

```
  getActivityDetails(activity_id){
this.displayModal = true;
this.loadingModal = true;
this.activityId = activity_id;
this.schedule = [];
this.hasScheduleData = false;
this._entertainmentService.getActivitySchedule(activity_id, this._translate.currentLang).subscribe(
  response => {
    for(var i=0; i<this.activities.length; i++){
      if(this.activityId == this.activities[i].id){
        this.currentActivity = this.activities[i];
      }
    }
   
    if(response.horarios_aperturas){
      if(response.horarios_aperturas.length > 0){
        this.hasScheduleData = true;
        this.schedule = response.horarios_aperturas;
      }                             
    }
    this.loadingModal = false; 
    this.ngxLoader.stop();
  },
  error => {
    this.loadingModal = false; 
    this.ngxLoader.stop();
    this.error = true;
  }
);
}
```

Al entrar a la web, me deja el espacio de la impresión de los datos en blanco
[image: Y si se usa el botón imprime los datos del seleccionado en todos]

La web tiene 3 secciones, ya resolví el problema de las otras 2, pero este es diferentes, ya que la llamada de los datos en las 2 primeras viene de la misma API y en esta son 2 API´s que traen la info, y el proyecto no está bien documentado

---

ACTUALIZACIÓN

Note que en mi component.ts en esta función

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
this.lang = this._translate.currentLang;
this.getActivities(this._translate.currentLang);
}
```

es donde se hace llamada a los datos para imprimirlos en la carga de la web, así que agregué la siguiente llamada

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
this.lang = this._translate.currentLang; /* TRAE LENGUAJE*/
this.getActivities(this._translate.currentLang); /* LLAMA DESCRIPCIONES*/
this.getActivityDetails(this.activityId);/* LLAMA LOS DATOS DE APERTURAS */
}
```

esto trae la información al cargar la web, como se ve, ya me hace la llamada a la api, pero solo falta que me traiga los datos de todos los ID ya que aparece como "undefined"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo hacer que en mi `ngOnInit(): void{` me llame todos los id?

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.getActivityDetails(this.activityId);/* LLAMA LOS DATOS DE APERTURAS */
}
```

Comment: Hay alguna manera de mandar a llamar el método que se usa en el botón al cargar la web?
`(click)="getActivityDetails(activity.id)`
ese es el método que imprime los datos que necesito, leí sobre el OnLoad en angular, pero no estoy seguro de que sea ese

Answer (score 1):

segun entiendo el problema es... como pinto los datos sin usar un boton para ejecutar el metodo que los trae, para este caso Angular usa Pipes, asi por ejemplo cuando usas:

```
<span> {{"RESTAURANT.restaurant_availabilityDays" | translate}} </span>
```

el " | translate" es un pipe, un metodo asincrono que solito va y ejecuta el metodo de traducir... el plan seria crear una pipe personalizada para traer los dias que requieres:

1. Crea la Pipe como un .ts asi => diasDisponibles.pipe.ts y dentro coloca:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Pipe({
  name: 'diasDisponible'
})

export class DiasDisponiblesPipe implements PipeTransform {

   constructor(
    private entertainmentService: ServiceEntreiment, // tu servicio que consulta back 
    ) { }

  transform(activivty: any, translate: any): any {
    this.entertainmentService.getActivitySchedule(activivty, translate)
    .pipe(map((response: any) => {
        if(response.horarios_aperturas.length > 0){
            return response.horarios_aperturas
        }
        
    }))
  }

  
}
```

y luego en el template:

```
<span class="rest-day-lbl">
  <strong>
   {{ (activity : translateOpt | diasDisponible).hora_inicio | async }} -
   {{ (activity : translateOpt | diasDisponible).hora_final | async }} 
  </strong>    
</span>
```

Te dejo un tutotial para ver mas acerca de crear pipes: https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/crear-usar-pipes-angular

Es recomendable tener un modulo compartido con todas las pipes y asi exportarlas a todas partes.

Exitos!

Comment: agregué el código a mi template y me salen estos errores
**Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Missing expected ) at column 12 in [ {{ (activity : translateOpt | diasDisponible).hora_inicio | async }}**

agregué el pipe.ts al igual que en el app.module.ts

Comment: @JhonnyEliezer Probablemente la data que esta llegando no sea compatible con el formato esperado... coloca logs dentro del pipe y revisa que la data que recibe y la que manda de salida. Si te es posible subir una version pequeña de tu app en https://stackblitz.com para revisarla podria darte mas apoyo en una solucion